# Draw circle using latitude and longitude

Tags: matlab, google-maps, geolocation, gps

I want to plot a latitude and longitude using matlab. Using that latitude and longitude as center of the circle, I want to plot a circle of radius 5 Nm.

```
r    = 5/60;
nseg = 100;

x = 25.01;
y = 55.01;

theta = 0 : (2 * pi / nseg) : (2 * pi);
pline_x = r * cos(theta) + x;
pline_y = r * sin(theta) + y;

hold all
geoshow(pline_x, pline_y)
geoshow(x, y)
```

The circle does not look of what I expected.

Comment: What does it look like? [Here is a circle on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donut.html) (are you accounting for the map's projection?

Comment: updated my answer. even when done correctly a circle looks like a circle only in the center of the projection. (Tissot's Error ellipse)

Comment: I found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/onedrive/en-US/33878b72-08ca-4c3b-8291-75bd4f43b776/draw-a-circle-given-a-latlong-and-radius-in-miles?forum=vemapcontroldev could be useful

Answer (score 3):

Drawing a circle on earth is more complex that it looks like.

Drawing a line or a poly line is simple, because the vertices are defined.
Not so on circle.
a circle is defined by all points having the same distance from center (in meters! not in degrees!!!) 
Unfortuantley lat and lon coordinates have not the same scale.

(The distance between two degrees of latidtude is always approx. 111.3 km, while for longitude this is only true at the equator. At the poles the distance between two longitudes approach zero. In Europe the factor is about 0.6. (cos(48deg))

There are two solution, the first is more universal, usefull for nearly all problems.

1. convert spherical coordinate (of circle center) to cartesian plane with unit = 1m, using a transformation (e.g equidistant transformation, also called equirectangular transf., this transformation works with the cos(centerLat) compensation factor)
2. calculate points (e.g circle points) in x,y plane using school mathematics.
3. transform all (x,y) points back to spherical (lat, lon) coordinates, using the inverse transformation of point 1.

Other solution
1. write a function which draws an ellipse in defined rectangle (all cartesian x,y)
2. define bounding of the circle to draw: 
2a: calculate north-south diameter of circle/ in degrees: this a bit tricky: the distance is define in meters, you need a transformation to get the latitudeSpan: one degrees of lat is approx 111.3 km (eart circumence / 360.0): With this meters_per_degree value  calc the N-S disatcne in degrees.
2b: calculate E-W span in degrees: now more tricky: calculate like 2a, but now divide by cos(centerLatitude) to compensate that E-W distances need more degrees when moving north to have the same meters.

Now draw ellipseInRectangle using N-S and E_W span for heigh and width.

But a circle on a sphere looks on the projected monitor display (or paper) only like a circle in the center of the projection. This shows:

[Tissot's Error Ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix)